# Build Docker image from GitHub repository

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-build, docker-api

I'm trying to build docker image from a GitHub repository using docker api python client.

Here's what I have tried:
**From views.py**

```
        if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.POST.copy()
        post_data.update({'user': request.user.pk})
        form = TarFromGithubForm(post_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            deployment = gitHubModel()
            deployment.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            deployment.user = request.user
            deployment.archive = form.cleaned_data['archive']
            dpath = deployment.archive
            print(deployment.archive)
            deployment.save()
            tag = deployment.name.lower()
            client = docker.from_env()
            client.images.build(path=dpath, tag=tag)
            messages.success(request, 'Your deployment from github repository has been created successfully!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:deployments:repo'))
```

Here in archive input field user will provide github repository url.

it throws an error:

> APIError at /user/deployment/new/github
>   500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("error detecting content type for remote https://github.com/Abdul-Rehman-yousaf/testing: unsupported Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"")
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/deployment/new/github
>   Django Version: 1.11.3
>   Exception Type: APIError
>   Exception Value:
>   500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("error detecting content type for remote https://github.com/Abdul-Rehman-yousaf/testing: unsupported Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"")
>   Exception Location: /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/errors.py in create_api_error_from_http_exception, line 31
>   Python Executable:  /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/bin/python
>   Python Version: 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

`detecting content type for remote` `unsupported Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8""` Are you sure that you passed the right url ? If in this case you want the Dockerfile it will be in: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Abdul-Rehman-yousaf/testing/master/Dockerfile

You can make a simple http request using `wget` to make sure that you are passing the right url:

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Abdul-Rehman yousaf/testing/master/Dockerfile`

so It seems that your are passing a wrong url, another way is to clone the repo and pass the code to the Dockerfile and it will follow it's content process by copying the desired file or folders to the container and so on....

Comment: I'm passing repository url as : `https://github.com/Abdul-Rehman-yousaf/testing`    and dockerfile is in root

Comment: does user needs to pass dockerfile url instead of main repository url in which dockefile in root of this repository?

Comment: Making an http request to the main github repo is not the right way to use a git repo, so passing the main repo to an http request like python request will response with an [ text/html ] as you see from the trackback, what you need in that case is to clone the repo using github api and after cloning the repo make sure you are passing your code to the Dockerfile as this is the only file you can build you container with.

Comment: I have tried that method already, in that case the problem is directory, how I have tried that is I have created a temporary directory and clone GitHub repository into that then how I can give path of that directory to docker build method?

Comment: Now if I pass `https://github.com/Abdul-Rehman-yousaf/testing.git`. git path of repository it gives a BuildError as  `The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: That error from docker itself, it means that the container provisioning failed to detect package.json be aware that you need the full git repo to be browseable through your code process not just the Dockerfile.